# Import can not be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, bitbucket

I have cloned a repository from bitbucket using git. I am using eclipse to work on that project. It is a maven project. For a certain java file it shows error on the import statements for the packages and files from the same project. But for the files that are already in that project there are no errors showing for the same imports. Can any one give solution for the problem?

Comment: I am not able to answer myself, but you should include an example, possibly a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use ALT + F5 to update the project. If the errors remain, build the project with "Run as -> Maven build... -> package". If the build is successful, the errors will probably vanish. Otherwise, post a new question with the error message (if you cannot resolve the error yourself).